# Need to create a treelike struct of array of strings with separator

Tags: coldfusion

I need to do convert an array of strings, which is a list separated by "/".

Basically I need this:

```
[
    "label1/label12/label13/label14",
    "label1/label12/label15",
    "label1/label12/label16",
    "label7/label72/label73"
]
```

to get like this:

```
{
    "label1": {
        "label12": {
            "label13": "label14",
            "label15",
            "label16"
        }
    },
    "label7": {
        "label72": "label73"
    }
}
```

Is this possible in any way?

Edit: After [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741559/10483164) gave a solution to my problem, as I wrote it, I now need a way to even do it with keys like "+++ In work +++"

Edit2: The second [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52755688/10483164) works even better. Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you explain why label14 and label73 are value's not keys? And why is lable73 a value but not label16 or label15.

Comment: label14 and label73 are values because they are at the end of a chain. Like label15 and label16 are too. It must not be exactly like my suggestion, just something where there are not that much duplicates.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method also works with keys with special characters like "+" or "!" or "+++ In work +++"

```
<Cfset labels =[
    "label1/label12/label+++13/+++ In work +++",
    "label1/label12/label15",
    "label1/label12$$@!/label16",
    "123/label72/label73"
]>


<cffunction name="convertLabels" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="k" type="array">
    <Cfset var local = {}>
    <Cfset local.response = {}>

    <Cfloop from=1 to="#arraylen(arguments.k)#" index="i">
        <Cfset local.splitted = arguments.k[i].Split("/")>
        <cfset local.refPath = local.response>
        <Cfloop from=1 to="#arraylen(local.splitted)#" index="local.y">
            <cfif not structKeyExists(local.refPath,local.splitted[local.y])>
                <Cfset local.refPath[splitted[local.y]] = {}>
            </cfif>
            <Cfset local.refPath = local.refPath[local.splitted[local.y]]>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn local.response>
</cffunction>
<cfdump var="#convertLabels(labels)#">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfset arrLabels = [
    "label1/label12/label13/label14",
    "label1/label12/label15",
    "label1/label12/label16",
    "label7/label72/label73"
]>




<cffunction name="labelConversion" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="arrLabels" type="array">
    <cfset var structLabels = {} />

    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arguments.arrLabels)#" index="i">
        <cfset StructGet("structLabels."&replace(arguments.arrLabels[i],'/','.', 'all'))>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn structLabels />
</cffunction>


<cfdump var="#labelConversion(arrLabels)#">
<cfabort>
```

Comment: The structget function is the basic of my solution, but you can add a lot more robustness ofcourse to this solution like checking the list length etc. There is also an empty struct for the leaf nodes, which you can change quite easily if necessary.

Comment: Interesting use of StructGet. Never thought about using it that way. Might add a brief description of why/how it works for others reading it in the future.

Comment: This works, but only without the use of " " or "+", since this makes use of the dot notation. Tried a little workaround with the ["key"] notation, but it seems that StructGet only acceppts numbers as keys inside [ and ].
So next Level would be to get custom strings as keys for my struct ... Any Idea?
Edit: Marked your answer as a solution, because technically you answered my question correct.

Comment: It's not that it *only* accepts numbers. As you said, it uses dot notation, which means any key names must also be [valid variable names](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/creating-variables.html), like start with a letter or underscore, can't contain spaces, square brackets, etc... I don't think there's a way around that, other than replacing the invalid characters too..  At least not with any function that uses dot notation.

Comment: You'd need to write the same recursive function as the StructGet does, to be able to have full flexibility. That's what I started to do until I decided brevity was nicer to look at. But the other way is to have a mapping struct of unique label names to normalised unique struct keys, kind of like as a lookup table.